# Problems with first-child and last-child CSS selectors

Tags: html, css

I'm using CSS to target a specific element in the following code. The element I want to target is the last element in the first div (`.1g07`). I need to do this without referring to `.1g07` as the class name is dynamic.

Here is the CSS I use:

```
[data-sigil="reactions-bling-bar"]:first-child:last-child
```

And the HTML:

```
<a href="#" data-sigil="feed-ufi-trigger">
    <div class="_rnk _2eo- _1e6" id="u_1_k" data-sigil="reactions-bling-bar">
    <div class="_1g07">
        <div class="_1g05" style="z-index:3">
            <i class="img sp_I5ooBdwh_8A sx_9a2202"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="_1g05" style="z-index:2">
            <i class="img sp_I5ooBdwh_8A sx_1f77a0"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="_1g05" style="z-index:1">
            <i class="img sp_I5ooBdwh_8A sx_fbc017"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="_1g06">48</div>
    </div>
    <div class="_1j-b"><span class="_1j-c">12 comments</span></div> 
    </div>
</a>
```

It's not targetting this element though (in this case the element that contains the number `48`).

Any ideas on where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[data-sigil="reactions-bling-bar"]:first-child:last-child` targets an element with a data attribute called `sigil` that is both the first and last child of its parent.

I think you're looking for `[data-sigil="reactions-bling-bar"] > :first-child > :last-child`, which would select the last child of the first child of the element with that `data-sigil` attribute.

Comment: Your CSS is correct: https://jsfiddle.net/pzy1rpou/ ... but when testing it my end it fails.

Comment: Fixed. The source order of the HTML is often different depending on a number of factors. Your solution works though, so I am accepting as best.

Comment: The direct descendant selector (`>`) is unnecessary, as there is only 1 first and 1 last.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this

```
[data-sigil="reactions-bling-bar"]  div div:last-child
[data-sigil="reactions-bling-bar"] :first-child :last-child
```

Sample snippet

```css
[data-sigil="reactions-bling-bar"]  div div:last-child
{
  color: red
}
```

```html
<a href="#" data-sigil="feed-ufi-trigger">
  <div class="_rnk _2eo- _1e6" id="u_1_k" data-sigil="reactions-bling-bar">
    <div class="_1g07">
      
      <div class="_1g05" style="z-index:3">
        <i class="img sp_I5ooBdwh_8A sx_9a2202"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="_1g05" style="z-index:2">
        <i class="img sp_I5ooBdwh_8A sx_1f77a0"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="_1g05" style="z-index:1">
        <i class="img sp_I5ooBdwh_8A sx_fbc017"></i>
      </div>
      
      <div class="_1g06">48</div>
      
    </div>
    <div class="_1j-b"><span class="_1j-c">12 comments</span></div> 
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
#u_1_k div div:last-child
{
/* css as you wants */
}
```

Comment: The use of ID's and classes to select elements is not possible in this instance. Those are dynamic ID's and classes and will change.

Answer (score 0):

your CSS selector targets nothing, because:

- `[data-sigil="reactions-bling-bar"]` targets the div with the attribute `data-sigil` having the value `reactions-bling-bar`;
- `[data-sigil="reactions-bling-bar"]:first-child` targets the div with the attribute `data-sigil` having the value `reactions-bling-bar` AND which is the first child of its container;
- `[data-sigil="reactions-bling-bar"]:first-child` targets the div with the attribute `data-sigil` having the value `reactions-bling-bar` AND which is the first child of its container AND which is the last child of its container.

This can't work.

If you can't modify the HTML, I dont think you can do what you want, maybe with:

```
[data-sigil="reactions-bling-bar"] > div > div:last-child {
    /* CSS rules here */
}
```